# Show answer div on clicking submit

Tags: php

I am building a calculator to help people understand the cost of volunteering at their companies.

When a user clicks the 'calculator' submit button, I want the answers to appear but not before.

I am currently trying to use:

```
<input type='submit' value='Calculate' class='cta'/>
```

And the corresponding html:

```
<div id="return data" style="display: <?php echo (isset($_POST['submit']))? 'block' : 'none';  ?>">
```

The page can be viewed here: http://benefacto.org/calculator

At the moment it doesn't work at all! Any help much appreciated. Best, Ben

Comment: *"At the moment it doesn't work at all!"* - Being what exactly? checking for errors? any at all? if not... http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php which is pretty clear here as to why it's "not" working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visiting your page, you clearly did not give the submit button a matching name attribute for it, in regards to the POST array here `$_POST['submit']`.

Using error reporting would have thrown you an undefined index submit notice about it.

Therefore, name it `name="submit"` as in:

```
<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Calculate' class='cta'/>
```

*HTML sticker:* Plus, you have a stray `</table>` tag and stray `</div>` - `</div><!-- /#wrapper -->` (as seen in HTML source) but that is beyond the scope of this question.

As for the PHP part of things, you didn't post that (or much of it). So till then, this is the best answer I can offer you at this time.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: I think a first priority is to learn about error reporting - in the staging period. Thanks again, the adding the 'name' worked perfectly.

Comment: Fred, could you advise on how to attach larger chunks of php when writing future questions? (I'm new to stack, as to php!)

Comment: @BenDarlington Error reporting is a valuable developer's tool as is viewing the HTML source ;-) TBH, I only started looking at HTML source but a few years ago. It is a most valuable one especially when it comes to HTML markup, tags etc. Web browsers are forgiving to a certain point, but when something doesn't match, it could have adverse effects. As for larger chunks. If Stack doesn't limit you to a certain amount, simply paste your code in the editor, highlight it then hit the CTRL-K key. It will indent it automatically for you. Or, you can use pastebin.com and paste a link in the question.